# How v01 is found?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I have found V01 equals the following

[image]

I got confused how it was found . I Know I can find it directly as 
[image]

But I need to know how the first formula is found.

Comment: Write those vo1 and vo2 into the drawing (=stop guesses).

Comment: Done! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not found. It's calculated exactly like you did "directly". After completing the "directly" job some of the gain factors are manipulated to equivalent alternative forms by applying the next identities. The first one is the total resistance of 2 resistors in parallel and it defines operator II. The 2nd and 3rd are consequenses.

(a II b) = ab/(a + b)

(a II b)/a =b/(a + b) and

a/(a II b) = 1 + a/b

I guess someone from Leonardo da Vinci's leaque could invent a plausible explanation how the formula is more natural and simpler with operator II. I will stick with your "directly" version.

Comment: In some book they generate the first one before the direct formula, then they fins the direct one from the first line

Comment: do they show the generation process from more elementary formulas which have operator II ?

Comment: No they just write directly the V01 in the first form in my question. then they drive the second form from the first one.

Comment: Do they present simpler things in earlier pages systematically by using II operator?  Are they derived with II operator in the start?

Comment: No they do not present it

Comment: So, there's no evidence which supports assumption " presenting things with operator II is based on deeper understanding that should be also your goal". Let them keep their weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing more than a superposition theorem in action.

First set \$V_2 = 0V\$ and \$V_{o2} = 0V\$ so we leeft with inverting amplifier only.

$$V_{oa} =-\frac{R_4}{R_3} \times V_1$$

next we set \$V_1 = 0V\$ and \$V_{o2} = 0V\$ and solve by inspection (a voltge divider + non-inverting amplifier).

$$V_{ob} = \left(1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3}\right) \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \times V_2$$

And we move on the next step (\$V_1 = 0V\$ and \$V_{2} = 0V\$) and agai nwe have a voltage divider plus non-inverting amplifier.

$$V_{oc} =\left(1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3}\right) \times \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} \times V_{o2} $$

And finally

$$V_{o1} = V_{oa}+V_{ob}+V_{oc}$$

$$V_{o1} = -\frac{R_4}{R_3}V_1 +\left(1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3}\right)  \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_2+ \left(1+\frac{R_4}{R_3}\right)\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_{o2}$$

Comment: @Caro Is my answer wrong? Or this is something that you do not understand?